# trouble using modulus for cash register program

Tags: java

For my cash register simulation, I have to take the change due and print it out in terms of 100s, 50s, 20s, 10s, 5s, 1s, and ofcourse change. I have two questions that I'm struggling with:

1.) Is there an easier way to figure out how many dollar bills are needed for each one if any? My equations work but it' s long and I think there's an easier way to do it?

2.) When dealing with cents is am i supposed to do (changeDue%100)? 
changeDue is equal to 39.12 and I'm trying to pull of just the 12 cents, but I dont quite know how? Can someone please help explain to me?

---

```
    double changeDue = 39.12;
    double coins;
    double change;
    int hundreds;
    int fifties;
    int twenties;
    int tens;
    int fives;
    int ones;
    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int nickels;
    int pennies;
    double cents; 

    //calculations for amount of each dollar bill that needs to be given back
    hundreds = (int)(changeDue/100);
    change = changeDue - (hundreds * 100);

    fifties = (int)(change/50);
    change = changeDue - (hundreds * 100) - (fifties * 50);

    twenties = (int)(change/20);
    change = changeDue - (hundreds * 100) - (fifties * 50) - (twenties * 20);

    tens = (int)(change/10);
    change = changeDue - (hundreds * 100) - (fifties * 50) - (twenties * 20) - (tens * 10);

    fives = (int)(change/5);
    change = changeDue - (hundreds * 100) - (fifties * 50) - (twenties * 20) - (tens * 10) - ( fives * 5);

    ones = (int)(change/1);

    //calculations for amount of coins that needs to be given back
    cents = changeDue%100;

    quarters = (int)cents/10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator gives the remainder after division. In your example `changeDue % 100` divides the number by 100 and returns the remainder. If you provide the number in pennies, say `3912`, then this will work exactly as you expect. However, you are using dollars instead. So first convert the dollar amount to pennies by multiplying by 100.

**Note**

`ones = (int)(change/1);` can be simplified to `ones = (int) change;`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method to derive change less than a dollar is:

```
cents=changeDue-(int)changeDue
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) Is there an easier way to figure out how many dollar bills are needed for each one if any? My equations work but it' s long and I think there's an easier way to do it?

I have found an easier way for your calculations. Refer to the code and code comments below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double changeDue = 39.12; // The change needed
    double change = changeDue; // Used for the calculations of change

    /*
     * Add here possible change, use an array so that you won't have to declare many
     * variables This way if you want to add other possible changes you just have to
     * add it in the array But make sure the possible changes is arrange in
     * descending order
     */
    double[] possibleChange = new double[] { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01 }; // the possible changes
    String[] possibleChangeLabel = new String[] { "Hundreds", "Fifties", "Twenties", "Tens", "Fives", "Ones", "Quarters", "Dimes", "Nickels", "Pennies" }; // used for printing

    int[] coins = new int[possibleChange.length]; // Used for the number of coins needed for each possible change

    /*
     * Loop through all the possible changes and acquire the possible number of
     * coins needed for each change
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleChange.length; i++) {
        coins[i] = (int) (change / possibleChange[i]); // calculate the possible number of coins in the given change
        change = (double) Math.round((change - (coins[i] * possibleChange[i])) * 100) / 100; // Update the change and limit to 2 decimal places
    }

    /*
     * This is for printing
     */
    System.out.println("Your change is $" + changeDue);
    System.out.println("The change is composed of: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleChange.length; i++) {
        if (coins[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println( "\t" + coins[i] + " piece/s of $" + possibleChange[i] + "(" + possibleChangeLabel[i] + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

> 2.) When dealing with cents is am i supposed to do (changeDue%100)? changeDue is equal to 39.12 and I'm trying to pull of just the 12 cents, but I dont quite know how? Can someone please help explain to me?

I don't know why you are needing this process, but you can try my code below.

```
double number = 123.45; // Your change
int decimal = (int) number; // You will get the whole number part (123)
double fractional = number - decimal; // You will get the fraction part (45)
```